# My Django Login/Signup forms save everything except the amount

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms, django-views

I am making a bank website in which users can make accounts, withdrawal, deposit and see transaction history. I have been working on them for two weeks. The Login and Signup works and it saves the email, username and password but when I input the amount the request works and I get redirected without any errors but the amount(balance) doesn't get saved. I then tried hardcoding the amount and then change it later when a person withdraws or deposits. Still, the same results when I try displaying the current balance on the dashboard it stays blank. I have pasted the code down and I am using Django 3.0 +

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from accounts.forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages

# Welcome, Login, Signup
def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/welcome.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.amount = 500
            user.save()
            u = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            return redirect('login-page')
        else:
           messages.error(request, 'Invalid input or missing fields. Please try again!')
           return redirect('signup-page') 
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Invalid login credentials. Please try agian.')
                return redirect('login-page')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid login credentials. Please try agian.')
            return redirect('login-page')
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

# Dashboard, Transfer, Transactions
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    user = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'user': user})
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128, help_text='Input valid email')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Current Balance</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ request.user.amount }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Total Expenses</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Amount goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Total Spent</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Amount goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body extended">
                <h5 class="card-title">Credit Card</h5>
                <h4 class="card-subtitle" id="cc">**** **** **** 1234</h4>
                <div id="med-pad">
                    <p class="card-text medium">{{ request.user.username }}</p>
                    <p class="card-text medium">Valid Through: 07/22</p>
                </div>
                <p id="cvv-pad" class="card-text">CVV: 001</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 py-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body extended">
                <h5 class="card-title">Total Spent</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Amount goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I tried the models but they messed up the current login and signup form. I am using Django 3.0 and am fairly new so please any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to set an 'amount' attribute for an user.

If so: [the default user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) (the user model comes out of the box with Django), does not have an amount field included. You will have to [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) the user model and *add* the field 'amount' to it.

Unfortunately I cannot test the following, however I believe if you create a
**models.py** with the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BankAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

it should work. Make sure you do your [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/) after creating this model.

Comment: OK, I'll try that and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I did as you said and was successful in the signup and login with no errors but I still can't display the amount in my template but I can display other user attributes. Do I need to make any changes to my views.py?

Comment: please help I really can't understand how to display it in my template

Comment: Great job so far! I believe, from the top of my head, that you have to do a relationship lookup. Maybe user.BankAccount.amount? Let me know, if this doesn't work, I will try it out tomorrow (not behind a computer now).